# Regarding Resource File in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have created a Resource File as App.rrc(Root)and App_fr.rrc under App.rrh(header file) and have added two keys - value pair to it.
Now when i extract values in using object of resource i get only the values from App.rrc files but not from App_fr.rrc 
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Locale to french using the following code

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_fr, null));
```

Comment: Yes, or change the language in device options.